# Google API , get value from datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, google-api

```
google.visualization.events.addListener( 
          geomap, "regionClick", function(e) {
          console.log(e["region"]);
          console.log(data.getValue(e["region"],1));
          });
```

I use this code to see which region is clicked. The `e["region"]` gives the row number of that region, and then I use getValue to see the region(marker) name.

Now, in the console log shows up this error:

`Uncaught Error: Invalid row index 1. Should be in the range [0-14]`

How can the row index 1 be invalid, as it is in the range [0-14] ?

**EDIT:**

There you go, more code :)

```
     <!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   google.load("visualization", "1", {"packages": ["geomap"]});

   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);



    function drawMap() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      data.addRows(24);

      data.addColumn("string", "City");

      data.addColumn("number", "Numar anunturi");data.setValue(0, 0, 'Ilfov');

    data.setValue(0, 1, 19);



     data.setValue(1, 0, 'Giurgiu');

    data.setValue(1, 1, 7);



     data.setValue(2, 0, 'Brasov');

    data.setValue(2, 1, 6);



     data.setValue(3, 0, 'Buzau');

    data.setValue(3, 1, 3);



     data.setValue(4, 0, 'Valcea');

    data.setValue(4, 1, 3);



     data.setValue(5, 0, 'Dolj');

    data.setValue(5, 1, 3);



     data.setValue(6, 0, 'Neamt');

    data.setValue(6, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(7, 0, 'Calarasi');

    data.setValue(7, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(8, 0, 'Dambovita');

    data.setValue(8, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(9, 0, 'Prahova');

    data.setValue(9, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(10, 0, 'Braila');

    data.setValue(10, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(11, 0, 'Constanta');

    data.setValue(11, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(12, 0, 'Suceava');

    data.setValue(12, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(13, 0, 'Caras-Severin');

    data.setValue(13, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(14, 0, 'Cluj');

    data.setValue(14, 1, 2);



     data.setValue(15, 0, 'Bihor');

    data.setValue(15, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(16, 0, 'Bacau');

    data.setValue(16, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(17, 0, 'Maramures');

    data.setValue(17, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(18, 0, 'Arges');

    data.setValue(18, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(19, 0, 'Gorj');

    data.setValue(19, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(20, 0, 'Ialomita');

    data.setValue(20, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(21, 0, 'Bucuresti');

    data.setValue(21, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(22, 0, 'Mures');

    data.setValue(22, 1, 1);



     data.setValue(23, 0, 'Sibiu');

    data.setValue(23, 1, 1);





      var options = {width: 800,height:400};

      options["region"] = "RO";

      options["colors"] = [0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]; //orange colors

      options["dataMode"] = "markers";



      var container = document.getElementById("map_chart_div");

      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);

        google.visualization.events.addListener( 
          geomap, "regionClick", function(e) {
          console.log(e["region"]);
          console.log(data.getValue(e["region"],1));
          }); 

      geomap.draw(data, options);

    }

  </script> 
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="map_chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: Is it JavaScript? If so, please re-tag.

Comment: Could you prepare a complete example of this? That way, everyone interested could run it him/herself and check how it works / debug / etc and you would probably get better answers.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what is in the `data` variable. Also bear in mind, from looking at the docs for `getValue()`, the parameters seem to be rowIndex, colIndex - so it might be not liking your first parameter `e["region"]`. What is its value? Is it really 1?

Comment: Updated... I don't know if this is the exact code because I've deleted it, but I think this is what it was. I simply want to add a click evenet on the markers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem with the code you've posted - I can't seem to get the regionClick function to fire at all - but the error message you're seeing makes me suspect that your problem is that `e["region"]` is returning a string, not a number.

Try adding this to your function:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener( 
          geomap, "regionClick", function(e) {
          console.log(e["region"]);
          console.log("Type of value is: " + typeof(e["region"]));
          console.log(data.getValue(e["region"],1));
          });
```

Then, if it turns out you are getting a string, you might try:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener( 
          geomap, "regionClick", function(e) {
          console.log(e["region"]);
          console.log("Type of value is: " + typeof(e["region"]));
          console.log(data.getValue(Math.floor(e["region"]),1));
          });
```

Comment: Thanks man, I've never thought of that . Google should've shown the value between "" so that we can see it's interpreted as a string. This solved the problem : console.log(data.getValue(Math.floor(e["region"]),0)); (had to also replace "1" with "0", my bad).