# Column index is undefined in Google Chart select event

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm getting an undefined column index for the select event with Google Charts. There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317216/how-to-get-column-index-for-google-data-chart-selection-handler), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687776/google-visualization-chart-throw-alert-on-select-event-data), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991549/google-api-get-value-from-datatable) I've looked at, but does not solve my problem. My goal is to be able to determine when the user clicks on the "[ x ]" to remove the corresponding row from the table. Thank you.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Site');
data.addColumn('number', 'Logins');
data.addColumn('string', '');
data.addRows([['ABC', 123, '[ x ]']]);

function drawTable() {
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    visualization.draw(data, null);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(visualization, 'select', selectHandler);
}

function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = visualization.getSelection()[0];
    console.log(selectedItem); // output:  Object {row: 0} 

    if (selectedItem == undefined)
        return false;

    console.log(selectedItem.column); // output: undefined

    var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, selectedItem.column);
    console.log(value); // output: Uncaught Error: Invalid column index undefined. Should be an integer in the range [0-3].
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the table chart only returns the row with the select event, as the Table visualization was designed for selecting rows. I found this at the [Google Visualization API Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-visualization-api/datatable%2420column/google-visualization-api/3MrCJ6qnPsA/0LZ0LsURNG8J)

Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Events) stating only rows can be selected for table charts.